# delete a specific word in text file via batch

Tags: batch-file

Best Users,

I want to made a batch script that deletes a specific word in a txt file. 
I used the following but it didn't work

(Script that I used) :

```
SET /p word=device
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /b "Input_%date%.txt"') DO (
SET "fname=%%~na"
SET "fname=!fname:%word%=!"'
IF NOT "!fname!"=="" REN "%%~a" "!fname!%%~xa"
```

(Input_%date%.txt):

```
1015faf2da091b02    device
1115fbd4e0dd3b03    device
```

I want to delete the word "device" in every line.

Can anyone help me out!

Kind Regards,

A.V.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want sth like this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set x=device
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (Input_%date%.txt) DO (
    set b=%%a
    echo !b:%x%=!
)
```

But once you install sed (from for example [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)) you can do this with simple one liner

```
type input_%date%.txt | sed "s/device//"
```

I assumed you can forward output to another file afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for answering, can you explain me more about the code: What does the line > echo !b:%x%=! . and why do we assign %%a to b. and what is assigned to %%a. Can you provide link where I can read it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have another question: I execute the script but nothing changes, The file is the same as before. I will read and try it with "unxutils" if it works I will come back. But I want to use only build in features that comes with windows

Comment: @A.V.R [for /?](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and [set /?](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) will answer most of your questions. This answer just writes the changed contents to screen, you'll have to [redirect](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) it to a new file, then [delete](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)  the original file and [rename](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) the new one to the original name.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you for answering

Comment: @rostok  sed from unxutils works like a charm. Thanks both of you!